# Fork Chain using fork-off-substrate?

Tags: substrate-node, fork

I'm trying to fork my chain using [fork-off-substrate](https://github.com/maxsam4/fork-off-substrate) but when running the  `new chain` using the genesis file i.e `fork.json` is does not `produce`or `finalize` the blocks. How can I solve this or what is the reason for blocks not being `finalized` or `produced`?

**i am getting following error:**

```sh
2023-06-22 12:32:33  Idle (2 peers), best: #0 (0x3e1d…46c8), finalized #0 (0x3e1d…46c8), ⬇ 0.8kiB/s ⬆ 0.8kiB/s    
2023-06-22 12:32:38  Idle (2 peers), best: #0 (0x3e1d…46c8), finalized #0 (0x3e1d…46c8), ⬇ 87 B/s ⬆ 79 B/s    
2023-06-22 12:32:39  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0x3e1dd501b4db59fc98469a8aeb7a353a42c8a2b25e4699c0dd9b9c30112746c8    
2023-06-22 12:32:39 [115] ‍♂️ Running migration with current storage version StorageVersion(3) / onchain StorageVersion(3)    
2023-06-22 12:32:39     
2023-06-22 12:32:39 [115] ‍♂️ MigrateToV2 did not executed. This probably should be removed    
2023-06-22 12:32:39 ⚠️ Ethereum declares internal migrations (which *might* execute). On-chain `StorageVersion(0)` vs current storage version `StorageVersion(0)`    
2023-06-22 12:32:39  Prepared block for proposing at 1 (3 ms) [hash: 0x5f831cb083500e516e32fe7613bce1add9849f24185d9baffcc35e2a29cdd730; parent_hash: 0x3e1d…46c8; extrinsics (1): [0xcb0f…d372]]    
2023-06-22 12:32:39  Pre-sealed block for proposal at 1. Hash now 0x93d7c0b4c439265fc1b2cfc712529f8856537ff7400e34b058cb5b0f768aad9e, previously 0x5f831cb083500e516e32fe7613bce1add9849f24185d9baffcc35e2a29cdd730.    
2023-06-22 12:32:39 Error with block built on 0x3e1dd501b4db59fc98469a8aeb7a353a42c8a2b25e4699c0dd9b9c30112746c8: Import failed: Expected epoch change to happen at 0x93d7c0b4c439265fc1b2cfc712529f8856537ff7400e34b058cb5b0f768aad9e, s562472453    
2023-06-22 12:32:43  Idle (2 peers), best: #0 (0x3e1d…46c8), finalized #0 (0x3e1d…46c8), ⬇ 1.3kiB/s ⬆ 1.4kiB/s    
2023-06-22 12:32:48  Idle (2 peers), best: #0 (0x3e1d…46c8), finalized #0 (0x3e1d…46c8), ⬇ 49 B/s ⬆ 49 B/s    
2023-06-22 12:32:51  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0x3e1dd501b4db59fc98469a8aeb7a353a42c8a2b25e4699c0dd9b9c30112746c8    
2023-06-22 12:32:51 [115] ‍♂️ Running migration with current storage version StorageVersion(3) / onchain StorageVersion(3)
```

[image]

Comment: Copy and paste the errors as text instead of screenshots

Comment: I recommend using https://subalfred.hack.ink/user/cli/state.html#command-state-fork-off

Comment: @AurevoirXavier i was using `Subalfred` to fork my chain i am getting this error when i run my new chain

 `Error: Service(Client(VersionInvalid("Runtime missing from initial storage, could not read state version.")))`

Comment: @AurevoirXavier i am running my chain in private network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you mentioned above maybe coming due to the the `authority node`, when you are running your new nodes try to run it with `--validator` tag. It may solve your issue.